# A solution $y$ of a Nth order homogenous linear ODE has infinite number of zeros on a closed interval. Prove the $y$ is identically $0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\{x_n\}$ be the sequence of zeros of the solution $y$. Then by Bolzano-Weirstrass, there exists a convergent subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ converging to $x_0$, which is contained in the interval (by compactness + completeness of closed interval in real number line).

Then $y(x_0)=0$ and $y^{\prime}(x_0)=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{y(x_{n_k})}{x_{n_k}-x_0}\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{0}{x_{n_k}-x_0}=0$. Therefore $y(x_0)=y^{\prime}(x_0)=0$.

Now, I am stuck. I see that, if we had a first or second order homogeneous linear ODE, then $y(x_0)=y^{\prime}(x_0)=0$ implies $y=0$ identically. But I do not see why that is the case for nth order ODEs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you point out, for $n$-th order ODEs this is insufficient, since you need the value of $n-1$ derivatives at $x_0$. However, you can remedy this: you can use the same approach to calculate the $m$-th derivative of $y$, by $y^{(m)}(x_0) = \lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{y^{(m-1)}(x_{n_k})}{x_{n_k}-x_0}$ and then use induction.